# Tw invariant subspaces of W are in one one correspondence with T-invariant subspaces of V which are contain in W

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator .Suppose $W\leq V$ be a $T$-invariant subspace and $T_W$ be the induced operator on  $W$.
Suppose $A$ is $T$-invariant subspace of $V$ such that $A$ is contained in $W$. 
Now ,$(\forall x \in W,T_W(x)=T(x)) \implies (\forall x \in A \leq W ,T_W(x)=T(x) )\implies T_W(A) \subseteq A $ as $T(A) \subseteq A.$
So $A$ is $T_W $-invariant .
Also suppose $B$ is $T_W$-invariant subspace of $W$.
Then $(\ T_W(B) \subseteq B \   and \ \    \forall x \in W ,\ T_W(x)=T(x)\ ) \implies T(B) \subseteq B.$
So $B$ is $T$-invariant .
So actually the set of all $T$-invariant subspace of $V$ which contained in $W$ and set of all $T_W$-invariant subspace of $W$ are eqaul .
In some lecture note there is a remark that $T$-invariant subspaces of $V$ which contain in $W$ and  $T_W$-invariant subspaces of $W$ are in one-one correspondence . 
So I think that  if I take identity  map then it is sufficient to prove this .Am I right ?

Comment: Define a **bijective** map $\{$$T$-invariant subspace of $V$ which is contained in $W$$\}\longrightarrow$$\{T|_W$-invariant subspace of $W\}$ as $$A\longmapsto A$$